# How to improve my question to not be on-hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my The Workplace Stack Exchange post: [How to break the glass ceiling: How to get my next position of managing 50+ people?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/117857/how-to-break-the-glass-ceiling-how-to-get-my-next-position-of-managing-50-peop)

I'm still do not understand why my question on-hold, or should be deleted. I'm sure that my question can help many others, because it's not a private situation (Moving from coding, to leading).

And you can see that I got VERY GOOD ANSWERS, that can help others. It's help me to start a research on a new topic, buying books, and *learn something new about the workplace environment*.

The reason I asked here, because I have a very specific question, a goal, and the question is answerable. The answers you gave me, I saved, and I kept it for others I know in similar situation. (Before you'll delete it)

I'm not looking for a psychologist, I want to learn. And I'm doing so by asking questions.

Comment: I have edited the question, and remove many unimportant details. Is it better now?

Comment: I have edited the question, and remove many [un]important details. I think the details are important, but maybe now the question is better fit to be on-topic.. [Can't edit a comment after 5 minutes]

Answer (score 4):

I removed references to "glass ceiling" as the implication is one of discrimination, where the theme of the question seems to be one of a dearth of skills and experience.

With the edit, I will vote to reopen

Answer (score 3):

This is an off topic close reason:

> "Questions asking for advice on a specific choice, such as what job to take or what skills to learn, are difficult to answer objectively and are rarely useful for anyone else. Instead of asking which decision to make, try asking how to make the decision, or for more specific details about one element of the decision. (More information)" – gnat, scaaahu, IDrinkandIKnowThings

You are asking, "what skills/experiences should I do to get my next position?" in the question.

I would suggest making the question more about how to identify any needed gaps in moving to a leadership role like you desire. Rather than asking for a list of things to do.

Comment: I'm still do not understand, let's see your most voted question [How can I prepare for getting hit by a bus?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9128/how-can-i-prepare-for-getting-hit-by-a-bus) Following your recommendation, to be sure that your questions will not be closed, will you suggest to reword it to "How can I identify any needed gaps in preparing to hit by as bus"?

Answer (score 1):

I voted to re-open the question.